# Child Page Doesn't Pick Up Styles From Master

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, master-pages

I can't get my child page to pick up styles defined in my master. Here is what I did:

- I created a stylesheet `Main.css` in the root of my app

  ```
  body {
      background-color:red;
  }
  ```
- I created a Master Page `Site.Master` in the root of my web application

  ```
  <%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.Site" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
       <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
      Master Page`
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

This shows up with a red background fine in the designer

- I created a child page `WebForm.aspx` in the root of my app

  ```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:Content>
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        Child Page Contents
  </asp:Content>
  ```

But this doesn't show a red background either in the designer or at runtime. When I view source there is no css declaration in the file, yet it is picking up the master page because it displays "`Master Page` `Child Page Contents`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your Master Page to look like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Site.master.vb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title></title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    Master Page`
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to link the stylesheet in the head tag, not the ContentPlaceHolder one.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

with

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <title></title>
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

The link to your css sheet is inside a content place holder.